# WordPress Errors? Update Failed! data.min.js

Tags: javascript, errors, 500-internal-error

So I am getting this weird error anytime I try to edit or save a new page/post.  I activated a default theme and disabled the only 2 plugins I had activated but I am still getting the error.

I don't even know where to begin to troubleshoot this.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ended up being an error I had in the .htaccess file.  I replaced that with a default WP one and everything is good!

Comment: (If you answered your own question, 'checkmark' it so that others will know that was the correct answer.)